# Long-running postgres operation with temp tables accumulating locks over time

Tags: postgresql

Hello people of the DBA stack exchange. I have a very large Postgres 12.2 database system I'm working on, lots of TB of data distributed between many machines. All main tables on these databases are partitioned, with anywhere from 2 to 2048 partitions per main table per DB.

To ensure that operations can finish on time (as the databases can be quite large, and postgres does not always choose the smartest plan for large databases), I do a lot of manual optimization of queries using temporary tables, many of which also receive the same partition treatment as the main tables.

I am encountering an issue related to the temporary tables. The logs from many of my operations show that they run out of shared memory, which can only mean they have allocated too many locks. This is odd, as the configuration I set allows for up to 25600 active locks. As I monitor the accumulation of locks over the course of the operation, I notice that a good portion of them have a relation id of > 900000 & can't be looked up in the pg_catalog, indicating that these locks are for temporary tables.

```
select sum(t.cnt) from (select relation, count(*) as cnt from pg_locks group by relation) t where t.relation::int < 900000;
select sum(t.cnt) from (select relation, count(*) as cnt from pg_locks group by relation) t where t.relation::int > 900000;
```

The number of locks from permanent tables stays steady over the course of the operation, at ~6*NPARTITIONS, where NPARTITIONS is the number of partitions configured for the database. The number of locks from temporary tables seems to go up in leaps of NPARTITIONS after every main loop of the operation (which can execute an arbitrary number of times). The main operation loop looks a little something like this:

```
create stage
create temp1, temp2, temp3 partitioned by (some_field);
-- create partitions... and then...
do $$
for i in 0..n; loop
    insert into temp1 (select some subset of stage);
    call some_operation_using_all_temp_tables();
    truncate temp1;
    truncate temp2;
    truncate temp3;
end loop
end $$;
```

What I want to know is this- what is causing the accumulation of locks? Is there anything I can do to prevent it? I've considered dropping the temp tables & recreating them every loop, which while annoying would probably solve my problem. I'm hoping for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Is the `some_operation_using_all_temp_tables()` unique (i.e. one instance running at a time)? If so, maybe you could first attempt to use an explicit LOCK. Once locked by your process, it should not attempt to create additional automatic locks. Another possibility I've heard of is to use BEGIN + COMMIT because then you get one lock for the transaction, but I don't think that would be enough.

Comment: Yes, it is. So what you're saying is- if I acquire an explicit LOCK on all of my temp tables prior to starting the operation, postgres won't attempt to automatically acquire any locks for them?

Comment: I think I read that somewhere, but of course, I can't find anything about it in the docs... I would try with a BEGIN + LOCK + some_operation... + COMMIT (or ROLLBACK) and see what happens.